# Logging to console while in a SpecFlow BeforeFeature hook is not visible when opening a TRX file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, specflow

If you run a SpecFlow test via TFS, and it contains a `[BeforeFeature]` hook, if you do a `Console.WriteLine("blah")`, then view the resultant TRX file using Visual Studio, these console lines are not shown.
However, if you edit the TRX file in a text editor, then the console output is actually there.
eg in the `<TestRun\ResultSummary\Output\StdOut>` node inside the TRX is the output from the `[BeforeFeature]` logging, but this is not displayed at all when viewing in VS.
The logging from the actual tests will appear in the node `<TestRun\Results\UnitTestResult\Output\StdOut>` and will be rendered inside VS.

Furthermore, just viewing the TRX file is a royal pain, because in order to do so, from the build results page, you have to double-click the build, click `detailed report`,  click `Failed` and change the drop-down to `All` and click the top link in the resultant view to go to the run explorer, then you FINALLY see the TRX as a download link. Even once you get to this stage, if you click the link, it REPLACES the current TRX you are viewing in VS with the new TRX, meaning that you can only ever view one TRX at a time, and if you forget the name of the last TRX you were viewing, back to square one.

Even then, once you view the TRX in VS, it truncates the logs, so you have to click the copy link and then paste it into notepad or something.
Seriously, Microsoft? 10+ clicks and 3 applications JUST TO VIEW YOUR LOGGING OUTPUT?? Utter madness.

So, ideally, I would like a way to totally do away with having to view TRX files in VS, and ideally modify TFS so that the information that we need is presented directly on the TFS web page, without requiring another two applications and a dozen-odd clicks.

Answer (score 1):

On TFS side, there is no default way to show the test result attachment on a web page, but you can customize an extension to show the test result. You can get start from [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node), and refer to the examples at [this website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/samples-overview), as well as the [Visual Studio Team Services Sample Extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples) repository on GitHub.

If you are using VSTS or TFS 2017, then you can call [REST API to get a list of test result](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#get-a-list-of-test-results) and list it on your extension:

```
GET http(s)://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results?api-version={version}[&detailsToInclude={string}&$skip={int}&$top={int}]
```